# With or without 'the'

Tags: articles

I have the following sentence:

"In Europe, the transport sector accounted for 22 % of **(the)** final energy consumption"

Would you use 'the' or not? I'd appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct and natural either way—a style issue, not a grammar issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are often many differences on how often the article is peppered into speech. In some parts of the UK you will hear very few 'The' while it is used continuously elsewhere. The meaning is certainly clear in this case so it is up to you.